# Can I call a 'normal' static method from an Async API Controller method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

relatively new to WebAPI and Async so please bear with me....

I have a WebAPI application with a number of operations in it.  Essentially, these call SQL Server stored procedures.

It has been working fine, but I am looking to make it more efficient and robust by converting the methods to be Async.

Let me show one methed - as they are all similar....

## OLD Version

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public A_Class MyAPIMethod(Guid b)
{
    using (SqlConnection DB = new SqlConnection(this.dbConnString))
    {
        return MyStaticHelper.A_Static_Method(DB, b);
    }
}
```

## New Version (Async I think & hope)

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public async Task<A_Class> MyAPIMethodAsync(Guid b)
{
    var db = new SqlConnection(this.dbConnString);
    try
    {
        var Result = await Task.Run(() => MyStaticHelper.A_Static_Method(db, b));
        return Result;
    }
    finally
    {
        db.Dispose();       
    }
}
```

I think that bit is OK - I am just not sure what, if anything I need to do to my static helper method.
Do I need to convert that to be Async?
I have made calls to this and it all seems to work OK - I could just do with a sanity check please.
Any advise appreciated....

Static Helper Method....

```
public static A_Class A_Static_Method(SqlConnection dbConn, Guid A_Param)
{
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        try
        {
            if (dbConn.State != ConnectionState.Closed) dbConn.Close();

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProc", dbConn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@sp_Param", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = A_PAram

                dbConn.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                var A_Class = StaticFunctionToGetInstanceOfClassFromResults( reader );
                A_Class.rc = 1;
                return A_Class 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //server error
            return new A_Class(A_ClassError.beApiError);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null) reader.Close();
        dbConn.Close();
    }            
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe running the method on another thread and awaiting the result is more "efficient and robust" than just running is synchronously? Imagine I made a clone of you and asked you to do something. Why would giving the clone the task to do and waiting for it to complete be better than just doing it yourself?

Comment: @Daniel Kelley that was very well said. AntDC, Asynchronous programming has overhead and should be used as needed not just to use it. In this case because all you are doing here is running a stored procedure it is not necessary. If it is a long running procedure I would start there and look into making it more efficient. I would also not recommend having anything that keeps state like a database connection in a static class.

Comment: I did fess us to this being relatively new to me....
I was thinking about not blocking the thread as my API may well have lots of simultaneous requests....

Anyway, so how about if I had to call an external API from my API.
Would Async operations be more applicable then?  

Also, dbConnString is a property of my BaseController class and I pass it to my static method.

Comment: Oh and thanks for your input guys.  Appreciated.

Comment: "I was thinking about not blocking the thread as my API may well have lots of simultaneous requests". That's certainly the idea. The problem is that as-is you are blocking another thread to achieve that, so you win nothing.

Comment: I see - so if I had a number of tasks to run...I could create a few clones to do them and wait for them all with WhenAll() and then proceed.
In theory, the time elapsed would be the time of the longest task.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> var Result = await Task.Run(() => MyStaticHelper.A_Static_Method(db, b));

Passes work to a new thread. Releases the old thread. Waits on result in new thread. Now a thread can carry on where this left off.

This could be useful if you were running several such tasks simultaneously, but you're spending effort to relieve a thread by having a thread do stuff. That's all cost and no gain.

Where async wins is:

1. You have more than one async operation at the same time.
2. You have an async operation that is using asynchronous I/O so that the calling thread is released entirely.

The second is the more important, especially in web terms.

Let's consider your "helper" method first. There are calls in that that have truly async equivalents, and so we can create a truly async version:

```
public static async Task<A_Class> AStaticMethodAsync(SqlConnection dbConn, Guid A_Param)
{
  try
  {
    if (dbConn.State != ConnectionState.Closed) dbConn.Close();

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProc", dbConn))
    {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@sp_Param", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = A_PAram

      await dbConn.OpenAsync();
      using(SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
        var A_Class = StaticFunctionToGetInstanceOfClassFromResults( reader );
        A_Class.rc = 1;
        return A_Class
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    //server error
    // Why are you wrapping an exception instead of just passing it up the stack? This is weird.
    return new A_Class(A_ClassError.beApiError);
  }
}
```

Two notes:

1. I replaced your use of `try…finally` around the `SqlDataReader` with a more normal `using`.
2. Presumably `StaticFunctionToGetInstanceOfClassFromResults` calls `Read()` on the datareader and then builds an object based on that. You could add an async version that calls `await ReadAsync()` and then use `var A_Class = await StaticFunctionToGetInstanceOfClassFromResultsAsync(reader)` here for even better asynchronous behaviour.

Now that we've an async method, your controller can be:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public async Task<A_Class> MyAPIMethodAsync(Guid b)
{
  using (SqlConnection DB = new SqlConnection(this.dbConnString))
  {
    return await MyStaticHelper.AStaticMethodAsync(DB, b);
  }
}
```

And it truly benefits from asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Jon.
You've imroved my understanding of this.

BTW - My catch is not the most elegant but does the job in this instance.  Sending back an object with a response code of "API Error".
Thanks gain.

Comment: I'd strongly consider seeing if I could turn that into something that catches an exception and returns the "API Error" response much closer to the API surface, if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

No, the approach is wrong. In general, you should avoid `Task.Run` (and any other method that queues work to the thread pool) on ASP.NET.

Instead of starting from the controller and working "down", you should start at the *lowest* level and work *up*. That is, first examine your static method and determine if there are any naturally-asynchronous operations. These are generally I/O. Two jump immediately out to me: [opening the database connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.openasync(v=vs.110).aspx) and [retrieving results from a query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereaderasync(v=vs.110).aspx) (and it's likely that `StaticFunctionToGetInstanceOfClassFromResults` has more). You should call those with `await` *first*, and then allow `async` to grow naturally towards your controller (the compiler will guide you).

Also, as @StephenBrickner commented, you might want to take a step back and determine whether `async` will help you. I have an [article on `async` ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) that covers the primary considerations. In particular, if your backend won't scale (e.g., if it's a single SQL server instance, not something like Azure SQL), then there's (usually) no point in making your web server scale.

Comment: Thanks Stephen,
Yeah - I've taken all the replies on board and have "loaded my gun" for when I truly need async.
Ie - when I have multiple tasks to run that can run independantly of eachother concurrently.
As an exercise for myself, I have made one of my simpler methods have an async option, just for the practice.
Thanks